# Activity Memory Not Clearing

Tags: android, bitmap, out-of-memory, ram

For some reason, it appears my android app is not properly freeing up BitmapFactory allocated space when its activity is completed. My app consists of two parts, one part is a thumbnail viewer, the second part is the image viewer.  When a thumbnail is pressed, the image viewer (mostly just a FragmentStatePagerAdapter using a fragment with an ImageView in it) activity is brought up.  When exiting ths image viewer, it seems all the bitmaps currently loaded into memory stick around, even if I call a System.gc() after the fact.

The reason I think this is the case is because if I were to repetitively go into the viewer on an image, then leave it, then go into the same one over and over again, eventually the program crashes saying it's out of memory.  Before someone points me to http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html I assure you it is not a problem with sample sizes.  I can say this safely since I can load the same image without an issue, but if I try to close it and load it again enough times, that is when I get the OOM errors.

Has anyone seen issues like this before?  I've tried manually unloading the bitmaps, but it seems like nothing I do is actually freeing up RAM.  Can anyone point me to some RAM analysis tools or tell me how to manually cleanup these bitmaps?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you call recycle() on the Bitmaps?

Comment: @RickFalck I haven't been.  I tried it once but it didn't seem to do anything.  At what time do you call recycle()?  After you are finished with them?

Comment: On the page you linked to, click the link near the bottom that says **Managing Bitmap Memory**

Answer (score 0):

First off, make sure you are scaling the bitmap and the bitmap itself isn't too large, that's the most important thing, a memory leak is a leak, but if a bitmap takes 10mb the leak is the least of your worries.

To clean a bitmap properly, and my examples will be Xamarin Android so you'll need to do some slight conversions but everything should be named the same, you need to first, get the imageview or whatever container you have the bitmap in, then you need to get that items drawable, next up, you need to make sure the drawable is a bitmap, then you need to check if that bitmap was recycled, if it wasn't already, you need to set the imageviews bitmap to null, recyle the bitmap, null out the bitmap, and then call the Java garbage collector, this is how that code looks for me:

```
    public void CleanBitmap()
    {
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.myImage);
        Drawable drawable = imageView.Drawable;
        if (drawable is BitmapDrawable)
        {
            BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable)drawable;
            if (bitmapDrawable.Bitmap != null)
            {
                Bitmap bitmap = bitmapDrawable.Bitmap;
                if (!bitmap.IsRecycled)
                {
                    imageView.SetImageBitmap(null);
                    bitmap.Recycle();
                    bitmap = null;
                }
            }

        }

        Java.Lang.JavaSystem.Gc();
    }
```

That *should* free up all your memory, remove any references to the bitmap and allow the garbage collector to go through and free up those bitmaps.